# Sending array data from excel VBA to WCF

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, wcf, vba

My problem is, I want to send an array of strings from VBA to WCF.

c# code is :

```
[OperationContract]    
void SetSomeObjects(string[] data);
```

Here is the VBA Part

```
Dim data(2) As String
data(0) = "abc"
data(1) = "def"

Dim service2 As Object
Set service2 = GetObject(ServiceBindingInformation)
service2.SetSomeObjects data
```

The last line throws VBA

```
"Type Mismatch Error"
```

I have no idea why is this happening. Please suggest a way to send array data from VBA to WCF Service
If I used object as the argument type, it gives error as shown in the attached screenshot

Comment: even with void SetSomeObjects(object data) , i get error "Type 'System.String[]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfstring:schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/serialization/array is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer"

Comment: Have you tried to declare the string[] data with ref keyword: void SetSomeObjects(ref string[] data)? And Dim data(0 to 1) As string? Or dim data(0 to 1) as variant?

Comment: Yup I did. Type Mismatch again! Here is what i did

Comment: [OperationContract]
     
      void SetSomeObjects(ref string[] data);

Comment: Dim dataf(0 To 1) As String

dataf(0) = "A"
dataf(1) = "B"

Comment: service2.SetSomeObjects dataf

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within C# code.

Once I wanted to sort the array (VBA) based on Linq (C#). Array was passed to UDF in the way one pass an argument to the function/method:

```
Dim UDF_Array As UDFArrayLinqTest.ArrayLinq
Set UDF_Array = New UDFArrayLinqTest.ArrayLinq

TBL = Array(...)
Range(...) = UDF_Array.ArraySorted(TBL)
```

The simple UDF in C# was as follow:

```
public double[] ArraySorted(object tbl)
    {
        object[] obj = (object[])tbl;
        var filtr = from i in obj
                    orderby Convert.ToDouble(i)
                    select Convert.ToDouble(i);

        double[] result = (double[])filtr.ToArray();
        return result;
    }
```

I don't think it is the best idea but I stopped searching better one after I did that above which was good enough for me.

Comment: thanks i will try it and let you know. Is this for WCF ? my binding is Net Named Pipe binding

Comment: Hey, I tried it , it still does not work. How can the problem be in c# code when it never receives the array in the first case. Here is the code is used c# public void GetArray(object tbl)
        {
            
            object[] obj = (object[])tbl;
        }

Comment: [VBA CODE] 
TBL = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
Dim addr As String
addr = "service:mexAddress=""net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/Mex"","
addr = addr + "address=""net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/"","
addr = addr + "contract=""IService1"", contractNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"","
addr = addr + "binding=""NetTcpBinding_IService1"", bindingNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"""
Dim service1 As Object
Set service1 = GetObject(addr)
service1.GetArray (TBL)

Comment: Gives the error, 
"Type System.object[] with data contract name 'arrayOfAnyType:http://Schemas...." is not expected. Add any types statistically to the list of known types, for example by using known type attribute or by adding them to list of known type by passing them to data contract serializer"

Comment: My idea was prepared in C# VS Express, compiled and provide as COM solution. If you are going different way I'm not sure if I could help you.