# Send data from WCF to Excel VBA

Tags: c#, wcf, vba, excel

What is the best and most efficient data type that can be used for WCF to send data to an Excel VBA client. For example, if Excel VBA (client) calls an operation contract which returns a list of numbers, what data type should the WCF operation returns? And how does Excel VBA client receive it and load it as an Excel VBA array?

Comment: Have you tried profiling several options? Also, are you really after a performance gain in sending a list of numbers? What are you doing and where does it take more time than you'd expect / tolerate?

Comment: Hi Romiox, I'm totally new to Excel VBA and don't even know what the possible options are. Could you please suggest a few?

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what you are asking, but maybe this would help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200110/sending-array-data-from-excel-vba-to-wcf